# Matriz, Float, posição da matriz

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Galera alguém podia mostrar meu erro? Tinha que sair uma matriz 3x3, só preciso que a saída seja assim:

> ```
> 0 0 0
> 0 0 0
> 0 0 0
> ```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define linha 3
#define coluna 3

int main()
{
    int l, c, i, j;
    float mesas[linha][coluna];


    for(l = 0;l < linha; l++){
        printf("\nLinha %i\n", l+1);
        for(c = 0; c < coluna; c++){
            printf("coluna %i: ", c+1);
            scanf("%f", &mesas[l][c]);
        }
    }

    printf("\nMatriz gerada\n");

    for(i = 0; i < linha; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0;j < coluna; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", mesas[l][c]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ta tendo algum erro de compilação? execução? qual seu problema??

Answer (score 0):

Basta coloca um printf pulando uma linha no final do loop do I , para que sempre acabar a linha pular de linha

```
for(i = 0; i < linha; i++)
{
    for(j = 0;j < coluna; j++)
    {
        printf("%.1f\t", mesas[l][c]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```